# Where will Build Go

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I am thinking to use team city for a TFS project. I created team city configurations using TFS server. It is started and creating builds as usual. I was thinking to make the builds for my local version of TFS checked out directory before putting it live. Can anyone please suggest where my current builds are going and can I do something what I am thinking.

help please !!

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear what you're asking, can you add more information, or reword your question?

Comment: @Nanhydrin I was unaware of where Team City is putting my build .. later I got to know that it checkout to local workspace dircetory called work inside team city installation folder. Anyhow can we change this checkout location

Comment: The directory that the code is checked out to, and where the build is run is a setting on the TeamCity build agent. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Checkout+Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working directory, the same as TFS build agent working directly.

> Agent work directory is the directory on a build agent that is used as
>   a containing directory for the default checkout directories.  By
>   default, this is the [Build agent home](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Agent+Home+Directory)  /work directory.
>
> **To modify the default directory location**, see `workDir` parameter in
>   [Build Agent Configuration.](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Agent+Configuration)
>
> Source: [Agent Work Directory](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Agent+Work+Directory)

To change this checkout location, you just need to change the `workDir=../work` of the ***buildagent.properties*** file (which stored in the /conf/)

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Can you please look at and suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305526/schedule-trigger-build-fails-on-team-city

Comment: It seems only related to Team City Build. Sorry, I'm not familiar with this. My area of expertise is with TFS and VSTS.  Can not give too much advice.

Comment: No issues!! Anyway Thanks for your help