# Schedule trigger Build Fails on Team City

Tags: teamcity

I have two triggers in Team City. VCS Trigger and Schedule trigger. VCS trigger works fine with every commit and builds successfully while **schedule trigger's build fails** and gives compilation error which was one in an earlier version of Checkin. Is it something that for this trigger team city is picking an earlier version of checkin not the latest one?

Can we set it to pick latest version? Please Help!!

**Edit:** Build Failure info

```
Build failure reason Compilation error: 

Web\MySystems.Web.UI\MySystems.Web.UI.csproj 
Open in IDE
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(28, 13): error CS0012: The type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.2.3.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(28, 47): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(28, 70): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(31, 38): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(31, 61): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(72, 47): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(72, 70): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(75, 38): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(75, 61): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 29): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 52): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 68): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 89): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 27): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 50): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 66): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 87): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
```

Adding Build Logs

```
[15:38:32][GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute] Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
[15:38:32][Web\MySys.Web.UI\MySys.Web.UI.csproj] CoreCompile
[15:38:32][CoreCompile] Csc
[15:38:32][Csc] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\AutoMapper.4.1.1\lib\net45\AutoMapper.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Grid.Mvc.3.0.0\lib\net40\GridMvc.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Cors.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Cors.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.3\lib\portable-net4+sl5+netcore45+wpa81+wp8\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Unity.Mvc.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll /reference:"C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Dependency Files\MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Dependency Files\MongoDB.Driver.dll" /reference:"C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Dependency Files\MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\mscorlib.dll" /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\PagedBil.1.17.0.0\lib\net40\PagedBil.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\PagedBil.Mvc.4.5.0.0\lib\net40\PagedBil.Mvc.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Business\Data\MySys.Business.Data.Repository\bin\Debug\MySys.Business.Data.Repository.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Business\Service\MySys.Business.Services\bin\Debug\MySys.Business.Services.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Core\MySys.Core.DataContracts\bin\Debug\MySys.Core.DataContracts.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Core\MySys.Core\bin\Debug\MySys.Core.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Core\MySys.Core.ServiceContracts\bin\Debug\MySys.Core.ServiceContracts.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Shared\MySys.Infrastructure.Identity\bin\Debug\MySys.Infrastructure.Identity.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Shared\MySys.Shared.Infrastructure\bin\Debug\MySys.Shared.Infrastructure.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\Web\MySys.Web.Infrastructure\bin\Debug\MySys.Web.Infrastructure.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.IdentityModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Cors.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.Entity.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.Routing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.Services.dll" /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\WebActivatorEx.2.0\lib\net40\WebActivatorEx.dll /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\MySys.Web.UI.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output ..\..\SolutionItems\VersionInfo.cs ActionFilters\SessionActionFilter.cs ActionFilters\UnderMaintainanceActionFilter.cs Api\EmployeeController.cs App_Start\BundleConfig.cs App_Start\FilterConfig.cs App_Start\RouteConfig.cs App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs App_Start\UnityConfig.cs App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs Controllers\AccountController.cs Controllers\HomeController.cs Controllers\ImageController.cs Controllers\BilingBilController.cs Controllers\BilshotController.cs Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs Controllers\BilshotTypeController.cs Controllers\ManageController.cs Controllers\RecipientController.cs Controllers\ScheduleBilshotController.cs Controllers\UnauthorizedController.cs Controllers\UserController.cs Global.asax.cs Hubs\SignalRHub.cs Models\AccountViewModels.cs Models\ManageViewModels.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Startup.cs "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\AccountController.cs(21, 7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'MySys.Infrastructure.Identity.Utils' appeared previously in this namespace
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(9, 7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'MySys.Web.Infrastructure.ViewModel.BilshotManagement' appeared previously in this namespace
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(10, 7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'MongoDB.Driver' appeared previously in this namespace
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(11, 7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'MySys.Shared.Infrastructure.MongoDbEntities' appeared previously in this namespace
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\AccountController.cs(58, 41): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilingBilController.cs(170, 17): warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilingBilController.cs(555, 41): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotController.cs(628, 41): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotController.cs(688, 29): warning CS0252: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotController.cs(768, 25): warning CS0252: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotController.cs(803, 17): warning CS0219: The variable 'UpdatedStatus' is assigned but its value is never used
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotController.cs(985, 41): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotController.cs(1087, 41): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotController.cs(1334, 41): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(28, 13): error CS0012: The type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.2.3.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(28, 47): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(28, 70): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(31, 38): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(31, 61): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(72, 47): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(72, 70): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(75, 38): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(75, 61): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 29): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 52): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 68): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(207, 89): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 27): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 50): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 66): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments
[15:38:33][Csc] Controllers\BilshotStatisticsController.cs(208, 87): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'
[15:38:33][MSBuild] UnitTests\MySys.UnitTests.Controller\MySys.UnitTests.Controller.csproj: Build default targets
[15:38:33][UnitTests\MySys.UnitTests.Controller\MySys.UnitTests.Controller.csproj] CheckPrerequisites
[15:38:33][UnitTests\MySys.UnitTests.Controller\MySys.UnitTests.Controller.csproj] RestorePackages
[15:38:33][RestorePackages] Exec
[15:38:33][Exec] "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cb8cd64caf637969\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install
```

Comment: Can you provide any details on what the compilation error is or share the build logs?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd I have added log information

Comment: This doesn't really show any details on why the build has failed. Can you show the error information?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd I have added error information. Please check. Anyhow this error was in an earlier checkin not in latest. latest version is easy buildable

Comment: My initial reaction here is that this is a dependency version issue problem caused by the NuGet restore. Check the versions on the NuGet packages that were restored by looking in the NuGet tab. Are the builds both being built in the same working directory?